# How to select top percent of matching values between columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of a genes for which I've compared a few models predicting whether the genes are likely to cause disease. I am looking to select genes that appear in the top 25% of most likely disease-causing genes across all machine learning methods I look at. So getting the top percent of likely disease genes all models agree on.

My data looks like this (although I actually have more columns of scores):

```
Gene            Score1      Score2
BRCA2           0.7         0.7
SLC25A20        0.2644568   0.486816
GLS             0.4560175   0.6631010
IKZF4           0.7468294   0.2189585
NRIP3           0.8446390   0.4570968
SENP1           0.5372014   0.1724868
SLC27A6         0.6321821   0.1218227
SRFBP1          0.2293986   0.2688244
OBFC1           0.2279012   0.2187441
STEAP2          0.2239941   0.2001475
```

So with this example `BRCA2` is the only gene that both model scores agree on as having a high score that is in the top 25% in this example, and so should be pulled out.

I'm not sure how to do this, I've been trying to use `match()` and if statements but haven't got far  - any help would be appreciated.

```
#Input data:
structure(list(Gene = c("BRCA2", "SLC25A20", "GLS", "IKZF4", 
"NRIP3", "SENP1", "SLC27A6", "SRFBP1", "OBFC1", "STEAP2"), Score1 = c(0.7, 
0.2644568, 0.4560175, 0.7468294, 0.844639, 0.5372014, 0.6321821, 
0.2293986, 0.2279012, 0.2239941), Score2 = c(0.7, 0.486816, 0.663101, 
0.2189585, 0.4570968, 0.1724868, 0.1218227, 0.2688244, 0.2187441, 
0.2001475)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "appear in the top 25%" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
#identify columns with score values
score_cols <- grep( "^Score", names(DT), value = TRUE )
#filter based on colwise quantile
DT[ rowSums( sapply( DT[, .SD, .SDcols = score_cols], 
                     function(x) x > quantile(x, 0.75 ) ) ) >= length( score_cols), ]

#     Gene Score1 Score2
# 1: BRCA2    0.7    0.7
```

Comment: Thank you for this - is there a way to do it without needing all the columns to have "Score"? My columns actually have different names each

Comment: sure.. just feed them to a vector named `score_cols`

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(Reduce(`&`, across(starts_with("Score"), ~ cume_dist(.) >= 0.75)))

   Gene Score1 Score2
1 BRCA2    0.7    0.7
```

Comment: Thank you for this - is there a way to do it without needing all the columns to have "Score"? My columns actually have different names each